# JQuery get dropdown box value & text and set into textbox value

Tags: jquery, html

i have a problem with this code which i dont understand. there is a button with id 'append' which when i clciked the JQuery is able to show a selected Category & Item dropdown box values into their various textboxes which is correct but all the Items dropdown box texts are combined as one word ***(PensBookRuler) etc*** and displayed into another textbox called itemname meanwhile the Items selected dropdown box should display the selected Item text not by combining all the the texts in the dropdown list. NB: all the JQuery libraries have been referenced so i didn't include them, even though the Category select option has a change event that lists the Items options upon the Category selected and that is working fine but this code shown below is just combining all the Items texts when i click on append button instead of displaying just the selected Item text:

```
  Category: <select id="icateg">
    <option value = "C1">Stationary</option>
    <option value ="C2">Toner</option>
    </select>
        Items: <select id="citem">
    <option value="T1">Pens</option>
    <option value="T2">Books</option>
<option value="T3">Ruler</option>
    </select>

    <script>
$("#append").click( function() {

    categID=$.trim($("#icateg").val()); 
    categName=$.trim($("#icateg").text());

    itemName=$.trim($("#citem").text());
    itemID=$.trim($("#citem").val());

    iqty=$("#qty").val();

    $("#additems").append(
        '<tr><td><input type="text" name="icateg" id="icateg" value="'+categID+'" readonly="readonly" />' +
                '<input type="text" name="icategName" id="icategName" value="'+categName+'" /></td>'+
             '<td><input type="text" name="citem" id="citem" readonly="readonly" value="'+itemID+'" />' +
                 '<input type="text" name="itemname" id="itemname" readonly="readonly" value="'+itemName+'" /></td>'+
            '<td><input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" readonly="readonly" value="'+iqty+'" /></td>'+
            '<td><a class="remove_this" href="#"><i class="icon-minus"></i></a></td></tr>');
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: Fiddle would be helpful.

Comment: Something like this? **http://jsfiddle.net/DN4Dr/**.. also don't reuse the same `id` on all the inputs. Make them use a `class`

Comment: @Pedro Estrada: thanx...the jsfiddle.net link you provided just gave me the whole and exact answer. infact i have been battling with this almost a week now. am so grateful for all your contributions especially Pedro!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this

```
 categName=$.trim($("#icateg").text());
```

should be

```
 categName=$.trim($("#icateg option:selected").text());
```

same with this

> itemName=$.trim($("#citem").text());

should be

> itemName=$.trim($("#citem option:selected").text());